# How to discover or deduce FK relationships when none were declared in the table definitions

Tags: sql, database, firebird, foreign-key-relationship

At my work We have a Data management application used with firebird database which has 65 tables and 1.3 Million records. The person who developed the application and the Database is long gone. We are in need to develop a new application and use the same data. I will be developing the application using C# and I have already converted this database to sql server. 
The problem is there are only Primary keys and Indexes, but no foreign keys in the tables. One ID table is used to generate the ID's for all tables, and some table also have another ID field as well.
I am trying to figure out the relationships between tables but was only able to identify 15 tables. 
Is there any way to find table relationships in a database where there are no identifiable Foreign keys and no documentation? Suggestions Please?

Guys anyone?

Comment: You will probably have to delve into the application code to figure out the relationships in detail. Looking at just the database schema will only tell you part of the story, precisely because of what you stated: the tables do not contain foreign keys or other constraints.

Comment: Also, it might be worth checking (use flamerobin?) to see if any views/stored procedures show you those relations if you cannot access the original code.

Comment: @code4life I don't have an option to use the application because no source code is available only .exe.

Comment: @BaconSah I am already using FlameRobin and there are no views or stored procedues. Some of the relations i figured out was by using this common Table, which includes fileds(Bold_ID, Bold_type). Where Bold_ID is the sequences used in all tables, and Bold_type(also in all tables) seems like a number given to a table whcih is using the generated Bold_ID.

Comment: You could use the Firebird 2.5 trace API to find out which queries the application uses. This might give you a way to reverse engineer the application, or at least a way of identifying the columns used for joining tables.

Comment: You could also query the actual data - if one table contains **only** the ID values that exist in another table, there is a strong probability this should be a FK. Your database contains enough data to make "false positives" rare. You might even automate this: programmatically generate `SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE ID1 NOT NULL AND ID1 NOT IN (SELECT ID2 FROM T2)` and replace `T1` and `T2` with all possible combinations of table names and `ID1` and `ID2` with corresponding column names. Those combinations that give you an empty result-set indicate "candidate" FKs.

Comment: Thanks Guys for all the suggestions. Trying with Mark Rotteveel and Branko Dimitrijevic ideas.